# signed or be signed?

Tags: passive-voice

Shall I say

Would you like this book to be signed by the author?

Would you like this book signed by the author?

If both are correct, any differences in their meaning

Answer (score 1):

While they mean the same thing (sentence two is an ellipsis of sentence one, where "to be" is dropped), sentence two can be misunderstood to mean *Would you like this book, signed by the author?* wherein a book which has previously been signed is on offer.

If your goal is clarity, and the book is not yet signed, use sentence one.

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine. The second sentence is simply a reduced version where the **to-infinitive** is omitted. There's no difference in meaning between them except that the second sentence is less common.

Sometimes a reduced version *(without the infinitive)* can be a strong directive or it can express a desire:

- I want it *(to be)* done by tomorrow morning! *(A strong directive without the infinitive)*
- I need you *(to be)* there at 5pm. Please don't be late. *(The version without the infinitive expresses a desire)*